# Is there a way to pass only filtered events from Apache Flink stream to AsyncDataStream/AsyncIO stream?

Tags: apache-flink

So I have a bunch of logs in Json and a I have a stream that validates/filters out the required Json and that works great!

Now I want to use the AsyncIO to do a DB lookup from the filtered Json, but it seems that asyncInvoke is executing on each input of the stream instead of the filtered results.

```
DataStream<String> stringInputStream = env.addSource(flinkKafkaConsumer);

stringInputStream
    .flatMap(stringToJsonObject()) // Make sure only JSON logs go through.
    .returns(JsonObject.class)
    .filter(filterLogs("my-app")) // Filter logs for my-app
    .flatMap(jsonStringToJsonObject("someJsonEncodedStringField"))
    .returns(JsonObject.class)
    .filter(filterSpecificEvent()); // This stream works as expected, putting print() here only prints filtered events.

DataStream<JsonObject> lookupCarrierCodeStream = 
    AsyncDataStream.orderedWait(stringInputStream, lookupCodesInDB(), 3000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, 100);

private static RichAsyncFunction<String, JsonObject> lookupCodesInDB() {
  return new RichAsyncFunction<String, JsonObject>() {
      @Override
      public void asyncInvoke(String input, ResultFuture<JsonObject> resultFuture) throws Exception {
          // This seems to receive all events, rather then the filtered ones.
          System.out.println("Input:" + input);

          resultFuture.complete(Collections.singleton(new JsonObject(input)));
      }
  };
}
```

**Update**

It seems to work if I split the streams like so...

```
DataStream<String> kafkaStringInput = env.addSource(flinkKafkaConsumer);

DataStream<JsonObject> jsonLogsInput = ...;
DataStream<JsonObject> appLogsInput = ...;
DataStream<JsonObject> evenInput = ...;

DataStream<JsonObject> lookupStream = AsyncDataStream.orderedWait(evenInput, ...);
```

Not sure why it wouldn't work fluently, but ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying a function to a stream, as in

```
eventStream
  .flatmap()
```

does not modify eventStream, but instead returns a new stream.

So you want to be doing something like this:

```
DataStream<JsonObject>filteredStream = stringInputStream
  .flatMap(stringToJsonObject())
  .returns(JsonObject.class)
  .filter(filterLogs("my-app"))
  .flatMap(jsonStringToJsonObject("someJsonEncodedStringField"))
  .returns(JsonObject.class)
  .filter(filterSpecificEvent());

DataStream<JsonObject> lookupCarrierCodeStream = 
  AsyncDataStream.orderedWait(filteredStream, lookupCodesInDB(), 3000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, 100);
```

Comment: Yep! My bad! Thanks!